# How to grep match lines with positive lookahead?

Tags: regex, grep, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to lines that contain a certain pattern, but only return the string up to the pattern and not including it.

For example:

`this is a foobar line`

I want to match this line and return everything up to `foobar`, so `this is a`.

I've tried using `grep -oE ".*(?=foobar)" test.txt`

But apparently lookaheads don't work with the `-E` flag. Also, I'm using a Mac so I don't have the `-P` option available.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-P` option for Perl regex:

```
grep -oP ".*(?=foobar)" test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the foobar in, and then remove it using `rev` and `cut`, like:

```
cat test.txt | grep -oE ".*foobar" | rev | cut -c7- | rev
```

A little long, but it works